# Matrix/2D Array Hourglass Array Elements Giving Undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix, 2d

Facing an issue with array elements. In the case below, the problem set is as follows:

> Actually, there are many hourglasses in the array above. An hourglass looks like so:
>
> 1 1 1
>             1
>   1 1 0
>
> The sum of an hourglass is the sum of all the numbers within it.
>   The sum for the hourglasses above are 7, 4, and 2, respectively.
>
> In this problem, you have to print the largest sum among all the
>   hourglasses in the array.

Now my solution has been to loop through all array positions that are possible (middle position is not on the outer bound of the array). And summing up the hourglass positions around that center position.

The error, is baffling me, despite 2,2 being clearly within the array and the bounds. I am getting an error "undefined" for the array elements that are on the "bottom row".

Any help would be great appreciated.

```
function main() {

    var arr = [];
    var max = 0;
    for(arr_i = 0; arr_i < 6; arr_i++){
       arr[arr_i] = readLine().split(' ');    
        var len = arr[0].length -1;
        if (arr_i !== 0 && arr_i !== len){
            for (var j=0; j < len; j++){
                if (j !== 0 && j !== len ){
                    console.log("this is i " + arr_i + "and the j " + j);
                    var currentMax = 0;
                    currentMax += parseInt(arr[arr_i -1][j-1]);
                    currentMax += parseInt(arr[arr_i -1][j]);
                    currentMax += parseInt(arr[arr_i -1][j+1]);
                    currentMax += parseInt(arr[arr_i][j]);
                    //currentMax += parseInt(arr[arr_i +1][j-1]);
                    //currentMax += parseInt(arr[arr_i +1][j]);
                    // currentMax += parseInt(arr[arr_i +1][j+1]);
                    console.log("dumb ", arr[2][2]);
                    console.log("currentMax ", currentMax);
                    max = Math.max(currentMax, max);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(max);
}
```

Comment: can you post real code instead of a picture? easier to work with

Comment: @JordanHendrix added code! Thanks so much